# trying to load gltf file and generate model.jsx file in react three fibre

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

im trying to load gltf file and generate model.jsx file in react three fibre using

```
npx gltfjsx Fish.gltf
```

or

```
npx gltfjsx public/models/Fish.gltf -o "src/components/three/Fish.jsx" -r "public"
```

but getting this error:

Parse
TypeError: fetch failed
at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when LTS and NodeJS are incompatible. You need update NodeJS or run the command below.

```
npx ggozad/gltfjsx#fix-dependencies ./public/models/model.glb
```